# Debugging Cucumber Ruby in VS Code. Error : No such file or directory - exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, visual-studio-code

I am trying to configure VS Code to debug Ruby and Cucumber

I followed this article to configure the VS Code : https://www.kloia.com/blog/development-environment-configuration-with-vscode-ruby-cucumber

I am getting Error: `No such file or directory - exec. You can use` cucumber --init `to get started.`

I did searched on google, I found that cucumber is searching for features folder, but I already specified it launch config settings of VS Code.

Launch Configuration for VS Code :

```
"configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Cucumber",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/cucumber",
        "useBundler": true,
        "args": [
          "exec",
          "cucumber",
          "${workspaceRoot}/features",
          "-t",
          "@set_1"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: This issue by removing "exec" and "cucumber" both from args parameter in launch config. As these are passed to Cucumber::Cli::Main.rb as arguments of cucumber as paths option, hence cucumber tries to find feature files at exec and cucumber paths and hence throws error.

I hope article mentioned in question make correction.